# lamp stack is not working properly in linux mint

Tags: php, lamp, linux-mint

I am a newbie to Linux. I was trying to install lamp stack in linux-mint. I used this command `sudo apt-get install apache2`, and looks like this is working. I enter the localhost in my browser and it shows the apache2 ubuntu default page. but the problem is when I create a `info.php` file in `/var/www/html` this directory with some basic PHP code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, instead of showing PHP details and versions, it is showing me the the raw PHP code in the browser `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. I've tried some solution from StackOverflow [image]

but nothing works. how can I fix this?

Comment: did you restart apache2? using sudo service apache2 restart ?

Comment: https://blog.storagecraft.com/install-lamp-server-linux-mint-18-command/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not have PHP installed or maybe your php is not enable.

you can do:

For install -> `sudo apt-get install php php-mysql`

For enable ->

```
sudo a2enmod php7  
sudo service apache2 restart
```

this is important `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: it works, but i've one question, after typing (sudo a2enmod php7), why it's showing (ERROR: Module php7 does not exist!) ? and what is the meaning of (a2enmod) ?

Comment: a2enmod, a2dismod - enable or disable an apache2 module. you can find more detail here -> manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/a2enmod.8.html may be you have different version of php there